# PHP Code for grabbing second image on a blog post

Tags: php, image, counter

I'm using the following code in order to grab an image from a blog post:

```
function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
  $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
 }
 return $first_img;
}
```

Now, I would need some help to introduce a minor modification. Here's what I'm looking for: I would like the code the *ignore* the first image, grab the second image it founds and, if it doesn't found a second image, use the default image (the fallback image).

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of the [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) project, which lets you work with HTML docs just like jQuery. Takes the grunt work out of such tasks. Give it a shot and let me know if that helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

I second the answer @David gave you, but if you just need a quick and dirty fix you can do this:

```
function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $content = preg_replace('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', '', $post->post_content, 1);
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
  $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
 }
 return $first_img;
}
```

The trick here is using [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with the `$limit` argument of 1 to delete the first image.

Comment: Guys, thanks a lot for the very quick solution. I should have added that I'm a novice with PHP (trail and error, slow learning curve). I know nothing about QueryPath, but I'll make sure to take a stab at it.